# logstash input jdbc take mysql tinyint 0/1 as boolean true/false

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, input, jdbc, logstash

In mysql table, has a tinyint type like this, which just store 0 or 1 value like `is_mel:1`.

`is_mel        | tinyint(1)`

In Elasticsearch index mapping config is_mel as integer.

But from the logstash log, it show it parse the is_mel as boolean value true or false  like `"is_mel":true`, which will lead to below error,

```
"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception",
"reason"=>"failed to parse field [is_mel] of type [integer] in document with id '392289'. Preview of field's value: 'true'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually [a feature, not a bug](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc/issues/195) :-)

You can append `tinyInt1isBit=false` to your JDBC URL to disable that behavior

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testdb?tinyInt1isBit=false
                                                    ^
                                                    |
                                                 add this
```

[Link to the related MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-result-sets.html#cj-conn-prop_tinyInt1isBit)